# UIDatePicker not responding properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker placed in a view, the UIDatePicker doesn't respond properly to touches - only the rightmost column/wheel scrolls for all touches in the UIDatePicker. This is independent on where in the view the touches occur, even when attempting to scroll the date column/wheel the rightmost column/wheel is scrolled (minutes or AM/PM column). No special settings are applied to the UIDatePicker, I just pulled it into a XIB.

Comment: can you please share your code for better understanding

Answer (score 6):

Need to check the code first.
I think there is some other `views` on the `UIDatePicker`. So first check it in `XIB`. that it should be last on last `object`. And if you are using to set it by code than at the time the UIDatePicker is showing set it:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:datePicker];
```

You can check it by:
goto `setting(iphone home screen)>>Accessibility>>Accessibility Inspector>>select YES.`

and click on you `UIDatePicker` area it will show you the information on which you are touching on.

Comment: Neither of your tips on how to solve it did the trick in my case, however if I enable the Accessibility Inspector it works.